# How to highlight navbar links on page scroll in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I found an example in Codepen https://codepen.io/dbilanoski/pen/LabpzG?editors=1010 of what I am wanting to do in my React Application. When I scroll down the the page it should highlight that section in my navbar, which is sticky at the top of the page. My app is a single page that contains about 5 to 6 sections that will be index/inline pages, so as the user scrolls down, it will take them to that next section. What approach should I take to incorporate this? More specifically, should I just use React, should I implement React Router Dom? What is the best approach to accomplish this functionality in the most general sense?

```
App 

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Footer from './components/footer/Footer';
import Hero from './components/hero/Hero';
import Resume from './components/resume/Resume';
import About from './components/about/About';
import Contact from './components/contact/Contact';
import Navbar from './components/navbar/Navbar';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {

    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.navHighlighter);
  }

  navHighlighter() {}

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
        <Hero/>
        <About/>
        <Resume/>
        <Contact/>
        <Footer/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```
Navbar 

mport React, {Component} from 'react';
import {FontAwesomeIcon} from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faBars } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import './navbar.css';

class Navbar extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            addClass: '',
            showMenu: ''
        }
        this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
        this.toggleMenu = this.toggleMenu.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll)
    }

    handleScroll() {
        if (window.scrollY > 0) {
            this.setState({addClass: 'sticky'})
        } else {
            this.setState({addClass: ''})
        }
    }

    toggleMenu() {
        let { showMenu } = this.state;
        this.setState({showMenu: showMenu === 'open' ? '' : 'open'})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <header onScroll={this.handleScroll} className={this.state.addClass}>
                    <a href="#" className="logo">Jeremy</a>
                    <nav className={this.state.showMenu}>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#" className="active">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                    <div className="menu-toggle" onClick={this.toggleMenu}><FontAwesomeIcon className='icon' icon={faBars} /></div>
                </header>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 3):

Create `refs` for each of your sections say `sampleRef` that you need to keep track of. With the `sampleRef` you can get position of section by using `sampleRef.current.offsetTop`. This gives absolute position of elements in the page.
To get position of page use `window.scrollY`. Then you can compare `offsetTop` of all the sections with `scrollY`. The section which has smallest difference between `offsetTop` and `scrollY` is the active section.
To find that I use divide and conquer to optimize the compare method.

I have create a codesandbox check it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/highlight-menu-item-on-scroll-x0gzn). There you can checkout the file ScrollHighlightNabbar.js

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same exact problem too and this is how I implemented it.

1. Create forward refs for each of your sections.
2. In your onScroll event handler, create the logic for making a nav item active. Use the previously created refs to access the height properties of your section.
3. Set the active/inactive states of your nav items. In my case I made refs of the nav items and edited the classes directly through them instead of relying on states because I wanted to prevent a rerender on each scroll.

```
const aboutRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
        const handleScroll = (e) => {
            if (window.scrollY >= 0 && window.scrollY <= window.innerHeight / 2) {
                // Set states for nav items here if the user is on the first section
            } else if (aboutRef.current.offsetTop - window.scrollY < window.innerHeight / 2 && stuffRef.current.offsetTop - window.scrollY >= window.innerHeight / 2) {
                // For the about section
            } else {
                // Etc...
            }
        }
        document.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
        }
    }, [])

return (
    <nav>
        ...

        <li className={stateActiveAbout ? 'active' : 'not-active'}>About</li>
        ...

    </nav>

    <About ref={aboutRef} .../>
)
```

Something to that effect. I'm sure the code can be improved upon but I hope you get the idea. The above is a functional component so you'll have to convert yours.

I'm not quite sure if this approach violates any React 'rules' but it works.

Answer (score 0):

The best and easiest method I got was:

- **First:** Add a CSS property `scroll-behaviour:smooth;` to Html and body tags, this will make the scrolling smooth when section HashLink is clicked.
- **Second:** The auto highlight of Nav-links can be done by a using the `react-scrollspy-highlight` package it will do the task perfectly. goto https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scrollspy-highlight for docs.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `<NavLink />` with `activeClassName` attribute.

```
<NavLink to="#about" activeClassName={"active"} className={"anything"}>About</NavLink>
```